# iPhone Quartz - Open GL

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, drawing, quartz-graphics

Does anyone have an idea what do the mind mapping applications use for drawing: Quartz 2D or Open GL? What would be the best way to implement this kind of application? Any advice is welcomed!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Quartz is well adapted for that kind of task.  OpenGL is more useful when drawing textured polygons.  Drawing bezier curves and text is much easier with Quartz.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into [Cocos2D](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/) for this type of application as well, even it being designed to be a game engine.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go with Quartz because it seems to satisfy the application needs and will require less time than OpenGL.
I was wondering about the connection lines between the nodes. 
I'll have a scroll view, that contains many nodes connected with lines. I designed every node to be a UIView subclass which implements drawRect: and does some shape drawing.When i drag/move the nodes, i only redraw the dragged view which is OK. However i am in doubt how to implement the lines between the nodes, especially line updating - when a node is moved, its connections should move with it. Should i redraw all connections when some node changes the position? Is there a better choice that will improve performance?

Thanks